# Is it valid for my controller to pass a connection parameter to a service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using services in MVC. I have a service that perform work for the controller such as the following:

```
private void Initialize(string dataSourceID)
        {
            this._accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>(dataSourceID);
        }

public bool Delete(Account account)
        {
            if (!ValidateAccountDeletion(account))
                return false;
            try
            {
                _accountRepository.Delete(account);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I have multiple identical databases and the way I point my service to one or the other is as follows:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(BaseViewModel vm)
    {
        if (vm.SubmitAction == "Delete")
        {
            _accountService = new AccountService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), vm.DataSourceID);
```

Here I get the database to use information directly from the model.

What I would like to know is this an acceptable way of creating and using a service. Somehow I need to tell my 
service what datasource to go against and this if very dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing technically wrong with it.
So if you had 2010 data in DB2010 and you passed 2010 and the data to the view and
it passed it back and then somewhere build a connection based on "DB" and Year, nae problem

If you were passing DB2010, or hard coding it in then web page, then a peer review would be a painful experience for you. Grin.

Answer (score 3):

Samantha J,

I think you would be better working with interfaces to the repository and injecting those when the classes are instantiated. in fact I would recommend that ONLY the services know about the database connectivity via the IRepository IOC. In turn, the controller classes would operate directly against the service classes (also via IOC) and would receive a viewModel (for any HttpGet) and or a status if a post was being performed.

Of course, this is a contentious subject and having 2 people in a room will provide 3 different answers :)

Comment: Two different points really. I took the question as was it right to have some indicator of which database the data was in, in the view as the key point. Passing the indicator is a different thing.